# End With without With

Tags: vba, excel

This appears to be a fairly common question, but I'm not able to see the error even after looking over previous answers. Please help with the compile error: End With without With, that I'm getting. The error is on the first instance of "End With". See code inset below (made simple for easy review):

```
CB = Left(ActiveSheet.Range("D10").Value, 3)
RT = Left(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("HBR", ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D100"), 0)).Value, 3)
If RT = "P" Then
    ShtName = CB & "_TR"
Else
    ShtName = CB & "_ATR"
End If
RScenarios = FindCase(CB, "abc")
Arraysize = UBound(RScenarios) - LBound(RScenarios) + 1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CB & "_Summary").Rows(5 & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ShtName)
    For scenario_index = LBound(RScenarios) To UBound(RScenarios)
        If RT = "P" Then
            pTableName = "PivotTable" & CB & "abc"
            RName = CB & "_Rrt_"
        Else
            pTableName = "PivotTable" & CB & "def"
            RName = CB & "_Rdt_"
        End If
        Dsweepcases = .Range("Z34").Value
        Tsweepcases = .Range("Y34").Value
        .Range("Q59").Value = RScenarios(scenario_index)
        .Calculate
        Set pt = Sheets(CB & "Results_PivotTable").PivotTables(pTableName)
        pt.RefreshTable
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CB & "Results_PivotTable").Range(CB & "_RxPivotTable").Copy
End With
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CB & "_Summary")
    If scenario_index = 0 Then
        LastRow = 6
    Else
        LastRow = .Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 3
    End If
    Set Destination = .Range("A" & LastRow)
    With Destination
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CB & "_TR")
            CaseName = .Range("R59").Value & " + " & .Range("U59").Value & " (AM" & .Range("Y59").Value & ")"
        End With
        .Value = CaseName
    End With
    TempLastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    HeaderRow = TempLastRow - 1 - Dsweepcases
    .Range("A" & TempLastRow).Value = blah blah
    .Range("C" & TempLastRow).Value = blah blah
    Set DVal = Worksheets("B").Range(RName & Left(.Range("A" & HeaderRow).Value, InStr(.Range("A" & HeaderRow).Value, " +") - 1))
    If IsError(Application.Match(DVal, .Range("A" & HeaderRow + 1 & ":A" & TempLastRow - 1), 0)) = False Then
        DValRow = blah blah
    Else
        DValRow = blah blah
    End If
    .Range("A" & HeaderRow + DValRow).Resize(, Tsweepcases + 1).BorderAround Weight:=xlThick
End With
Next scenario_index
```

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me, I missed your `Next scenario_index` at the bottom. I edited the answer to instead reverse the order of your With block and For Loop.

Just FYI, using multiple `With` blocks inside each other can cause problems if the same line could be qualified by multiple `With` references. In my experience, this doesn't happen often enough to stop doing it, but keep it in mind for future debugging. If you suspect it is causing you a problem, try adding the appropriate reference to the line and see if your problem is fixed.

```
CB = Left(ActiveSheet.Range("D10").Value, 3)
RT = Left(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("HBR", ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D100"), 0)).Value, 3)
If RT = "P" Then
    ShtName = CB & "_TR"
Else
    ShtName = CB & "_ATR"
End If
RScenarios = FindCase(CB, "abc")
Arraysize = UBound(RScenarios) - LBound(RScenarios) + 1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CB & "_Summary").Rows(5 & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
For scenario_index = LBound(RScenarios) To UBound(RScenarios)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ShtName)
        If RT = "P" Then
            pTableName = "PivotTable" & CB & "abc"
            RName = CB & "_Rrt_"
        Else
            pTableName = "PivotTable" & CB & "def"
            RName = CB & "_Rdt_"
        End If
        Dsweepcases = .Range("Z34").Value
        Tsweepcases = .Range("Y34").Value
        .Range("Q59").Value = RScenarios(scenario_index)
        .Calculate
        Set pt = Sheets(CB & "Results_PivotTable").PivotTables(pTableName)
        pt.RefreshTable
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CB & "Results_PivotTable").Range(CB & "_RxPivotTable").Copy
    End With
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CB & "_Summary")
        If scenario_index = 0 Then
            LastRow = 6
        Else
            LastRow = .Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 3
        End If
        Set Destination = .Range("A" & LastRow)
        With Destination
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CB & "_TR")
                CaseName = .Range("R59").Value & " + " & .Range("U59").Value & " (AM" & .Range("Y59").Value & ")"
            End With
            .Value = CaseName
        End With
        TempLastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        HeaderRow = TempLastRow - 1 - Dsweepcases
        .Range("A" & TempLastRow).Value = blah blah
        .Range("C" & TempLastRow).Value = blah blah
        Set DVal = Worksheets("B").Range(RName & Left(.Range("A" & HeaderRow).Value, InStr(.Range("A" & HeaderRow).Value, " +") - 1))
        If IsError(Application.Match(DVal, .Range("A" & HeaderRow + 1 & ":A" & TempLastRow - 1), 0)) = False Then
            DValRow = blah blah
        Else
            DValRow = blah blah
        End If
        .Range("A" & HeaderRow + DValRow).Resize(, Tsweepcases + 1).BorderAround Weight:=xlThick
    End With
Next scenario_index
```

Comment: @jabberwocky this is fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

This can actually be caused by not having other control structures closed. The compiler can get confused and report this as a missing End With. Here are items to look for:

- If/End If
- Select/End Select
- For/Next
- Do/Loop
- While/Wend

And of course,

- With/End With

If you check to be sure each of these is closed properly, You'll find the issue in your code.

**As to why**?

You can think of each of these structures like [Russian nesting dolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll#As_metaphor). You have to close each one before putting in into a larger doll. Likewise, you have to open each doll in order to get the next smaller one.

Take this mental exercise a bit further for a moment. Try to imagine how you would manage to do otherwise? In other words, how would you place a doll inside the next larger doll without first closing it? You could just put in the bases and leave all the heads till the end, but that's not how Russian nesting dolls work. You can't put the heads on out of order.

That is what you are asking the compiler to do without closing each item in turn and a compiler can only take explicit instructions, so it can not determine your intent.

For a visual, consider this structure. It's orderly and makes immediate logical sense. What makes sense is the nesting. Each structure is nested inside another structure.

```
--------+
--+     |
  |     |
--+     |
------+ |
----+ | |
    | | |
----+ | |
------+ |
--------+
```

Compare to this:

```
------+
--------+
--+   | |
--|-+ | |
--|-------+
  | | | | |
--+ | | | |
    | | | |
----|-+ | |
----+   | |
--------+ |
----------+
```

Try putting these nesting dolls back together by following these Steps:

1. Take the smallest body
2. Close it with one or more random head
3. Put this inside of the next larger body
4. Repeat

Ironman's head on Nick Fury's body and then put that into Captain America with the Hulk's head and put all of that into the Thor's body with Nick Fury's head. And then put that into Hulk's body. Good luck!

There's only one step above that makes this process NOT work.

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. I suspected this. I do have a "Next scenario_index" right at the bottom of the code. I don't understand why it needs to be closed inside the "with...end with" block. The for is a loop and needs to extend as far as it does in my code. The with is not really a loop, just a construct to qualify the workbook/sheet, etc and avoid repetition, correct?

Comment: Oh, if that's the case then you can just reverse the order of the loops. Editing my answer.

Comment: As for the why, I couldn't tell you - I'm self taught and am not familiar enough with the nitty gritty to answer.

Comment: Got it. I have already adjusted the for/with order and it works fine. A little irksome that this needs to be done. In this case, makes no difference and I didn't need to have it the other way. Maybe not so always. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Yes, the With qualifies an object. I've added an explanation which may be helpful albeit whimsical.

Comment: @Jabberwocky This is a complete guess, but maybe the reason was to enable Intellisense to be as helpful as possible for troubleshooting, and allowing you to close blocks in variable rather than strict orders caused it too much confusion/that is to say, the programmers couldn't figure out how to get it to account for errors and allow variable closing order.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have:

```
With X
    For Y
End With
    Next Y
```

The reason is when Y loops after the first iteration there would be no X as you closed the loop.

You can however set up multiple for loops within the With or have some advanced IF checks inside there.

puzzlepiece87 has fixed the code for you but I noticed you asked WHY it is like this in one of the comments.